# VS2013 disable Web Publish Activity windo

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to disable the Web Publish Activity window in Visual Studio 2013?

I couldn't find any options to disable that feature.

Answer (score 5):

I have no directly solution for it. But I found workaroud: I tab it to the right sidebar and set autohide for it. So, now this window take minimum screen place and isn't shown during every publish:[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

If you click the little x in the Web Publish Activity window, it will go away!

Comment: It will come up back at every publish!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Visual Studio 2017.

Mine was over everything every time and completely unreactive. Not even its close button worked.

The way I get rid of it was: menu **Window > Reset Window Layout**